# Check if PrimeNG checkbox checked or unchecked

Tags: primeng, primeng-turbotable, primeng-checkbox

check if primeNG checkbox checked or unchecked.
 I am using primenNG 5. 
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-5.2.7/#/table/selection

```
<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="cars" [(selection)]="selectedCars3" dataKey="vin">
        <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 3em">
                    <p-tableHeaderCheckbox></p-tableHeaderCheckbox>
                </th>
                <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
                    {{col.header}}
                </th>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p-tableCheckbox [value]="rowData" (click)="onRowSelect($event)"></p-tableCheckbox>
                </td>
                <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                    {{rowData[col.field]}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="summary">
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let car of selectedCars3" style="text-align: left">
                    {{car.vin + ' - ' + car.brand + ' - ' + car.year + ' - ' + car.color}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </ng-template>
    </p-table>
```

Comment: You should provide more code that shows your problem and you should have a clear question. Would like to help you, but your question is not clear

Comment: Here, `selectedCars3` should contain your selected rows. What's your problem then ?